# Running a Tor Bridge Relay on Ubuntu

Tags: configuration, relays, linux, bridge, ubuntu

I am trying to set up a bridge relay on my ubuntu 20.04 system but getting stuck at step 3. Edit your Tor config file, usually located at /etc/tor/torrc and replace its content with:

When I open the config file, do I just add the BridgeRelay 1 information at the bottom of the file and how do I know what Tor and obfs4 ports to use?

Answer (score 0):

The ports can be chosen by yourself. For technical reasons you should avoid the lower numbers. Let's say you can choose any number between 1025 and 65535. I Copied the config from step 3 and edited it as an example.

For the ORPort I have chosen 42301. For the obfs4 port I have chosen 37198. The contactinformation can be filled in if you like but it is optional. Your contact info won't be shown publicly if you run a bridge. It will be publicly shared when you run any other type of relay. And lastly, your servername. Pick any name you like, the network doesn't care. I named it 'RasputinBridge' as an example but using any reference to yourself could be a flaw in your personal privacy. So maybe a name like 'MyFirstBridge' would be better.

```
BridgeRelay 1

# Replace "TODO1" with a Tor port of your choice.
# This port must be externally reachable.
# Avoid port 9001 because it's commonly associated with Tor and censors may be scanning the Internet for this port.
ORPort 42301

ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy

# Replace "TODO2" with an obfs4 port of your choice.
# This port must be externally reachable and must be different from the one specified for ORPort.
# Avoid port 9001 because it's commonly associated with Tor and censors may be scanning the Internet for this port.
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:37198

# Local communication port between Tor and obfs4.  Always set this to "auto".
# "Ext" means "extended", not "external".  Don't try to set a specific port number, nor listen on 0.0.0.0.
ExtORPort auto

# Replace "<address@email.com>" with your email address so we can contact you if there are problems with your bridge.
# This is optional but encouraged.
ContactInfo <address@email.com>

# Pick a nickname that you like for your bridge.  This is optional.
Nickname RasputinBridge
```

Now that your configuration is complete, follow the next steps to complete the bridge. And make sure you forward the chosen portnumbers in your router (if required) so that traffic can flow to your bridge.